# py launcher in Windows : Selecting a specific python installation(all of them same version of 3.7-64)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I installed python 3.7x from python.org and then anaconda distribution.

Now if I run `py -0p`

```
Installed Pythons found by py Launcher for Windows
 -3.7-64        D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe *
 -3.7-64        C:\Users\joonhwan.lee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
```

As you can see they are all same version. How do I select a specific one?

It seems to me than I only can select a specific python installation only by version number.

```
λ py --help                                                                                
Python Launcher for Windows Version 3.7.3150.1013                                          

usage:                                                                                     
py [launcher-args] [python-args] script [script-args]                                      

Launcher arguments:                                                                        

-2     : Launch the latest Python 2.x version                                              
-3     : Launch the latest Python 3.x version                                              
-X.Y   : Launch the specified Python version                                               
     The above all default to 64 bit if a matching 64 bit python is present.               
-X.Y-32: Launch the specified 32bit Python version                                         
-X-32  : Launch the latest 32bit Python X version                                          
-X.Y-64: Launch the specified 64bit Python version                                         
-X-64  : Launch the latest 64bit Python X version                                          
-0  --list       : List the available pythons                                              
-0p --list-paths : List with paths
```

Comment: If the only differentiation is the path.. why not just call C:\Users\joonhwan.lee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe directly?

Comment: @JeffUK Hmm. maybe I should be able to run the script itself(using *.py file association with py.exe using shebang line) or in a more portable way regardless of python installed path difference.... and there should be several environment variables(like PYTHONPATH) pre-configured correctly, I think. Please comments.

Answer (score 2):

If your script is written for a specific instance of python you can add a 'Shebang' line, which windows will respect if you call the code from the command line

I.e.

37-32.py:

```
#!C:\Python37-32\python.exe
import sys
print (sys.version)
```

36-32.py:

```
#!C:\Python36-32\python.exe
import sys
print (sys.version)
```

> c:\test>36-32.py
>
> 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 07:18:10) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
>
> c:\test>37-32.py
>
> 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 21:26:53) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]